Efficently saving code from Python REPL without gui
I often use REPL in my terminal to quick test simple things.  With 3.13 update repl gets better and much more usefull so increased my usage but i can't easily save from repl.  My current solution is to copy paste from ui.
Is there any methods that allow me to save my session as a .py file or coppy last commands into my device clipboard so i can use it else where quickly?

You can use ipython in this case, Usage:
%save [options] filename [history] see more here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-save
